# How to change the background of a Row, based on a choice in the Row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make it so when a choice is selected from a list, it will change the color of the row, based on the choice made. I am using conditional formatting, using a formula to determine which cells to format.

Here's what I've been using so far.

```
Rule                                 Applies To

=$K2="Completed - OK"               =$A$2:$L$24992
=$K2="blank"                        =$A$2:$L$24992
=$K2="Completed - FAIL"             =$A$2:$L$24992
```

The goal is when one of the 3 choices is made in the K column, it will turn the selected row Green, No color, or Red. I want it to apply to entire worksheet. When a row is completed, it's cut and pasted onto another tab of the worksheet.

This seemed to be working well but the problem I am having now is that when a choice is made, the color only changes in the K column but bleeds into the L column, you then have to select cells within the Row to get them to acknowledge the formatting change.

Why is that happening and/or is there a better way to write my conditional formatting for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: The rules are correct - what else changed?